# Multiple unrelated scenarios in one feature file

Tags: java, cucumber-jvm, gherkin

For testing an APK, should I include all scenarios in the same feature file even if they are testing different functions of the APK? If I do need multiple feature files, do I need a separate step file for each feature file, or can I use the same step file for all of them?

Comment: What is APK and why should it affect your choice of structuring the features?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably separate the scenarios is many feature files.

Unrelated scenarios can live in the same feature file. But if each feature file describe examples for a certain part of the application, then it may be more logical to keep them apart.

Cucumber will not force you to do one or the other, it will happily execute the steps defined.

The separation is for your future you, or someone else, that will maintain the application. That person may thank you for separating the scenarios and therefore simplify understanding the system.

Answer (score 0):

You should create feature files for the different areas of functionality or different areas of your app.

Part of the benefit of using scenarios is that they provide executable documentation for your app.  If you're reading documentation for something you would probably expect it to be laid out in an intuitive way.  Creating feature files that have sensible groups of scenarios is the way of doing this.

This will also help with maintainability in future, as the engineer that is working on the scenarios will spend less time looking for the relevant part.

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice to have multiple feature and step files, with the contents split by logical grouping, e.g. purchasing scenarios all go in the same feature file, and steps to do with the purchasing workflow are all in the same steps file.

You don't have to have more than one feature file or more than one steps file, but it makes it easier to find what you're looking for if you group things logically, especially as your list of scenarios grows.

I tend to have a 'global steps' file with steps that affect scenarios across multiple features, and then a steps file for more specific areas which aren't shared between features.